# How to return int if BigInteger is too big for int?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, biginteger

i'm currently trying to solve a HackerRank problem, the problem in question is called Fibonacci Modified.

The method returns an int but it is expected that I will be obtaining huge values. I'm solving this problem in Java.

Here is my code

```
static int fibonacciModified(int t1, int t2, int n) {

    BigInteger[] f = new BigInteger[n];
    f[0] = BigInteger.ZERO;
    f[1] = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger value = BigInteger.ONE;

    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        f[i] = f[i-1].multiply(f[i-1]).add(f[i-2]);
        value = f[i];
    }

    return value.intValue();
}
```

I'm failing the test case when t1 = 0, t2 = 1, n = 10. My output is -1022889632.
The correct answer is 84266613096281243382112. If I change the method to return a BigInteger then I do get the right answer.

Edit: This is the link to the problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fibonacci-modified/problem

Comment: `intValue()` takes the lower 32 bits of the value, that's why you get a different result.

Comment: If you are trying to pass a test against 0, 1 and 10. In that scenario the test should be modified to test against BigInteger. If you cannot, please post the test code here so an appropriate workaround can be suggested.

Comment: Could you either fully describe the algorithm, or link to the hacker rank problem description.

Comment: Hi, this is the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fibonacci-modified/problem

Comment: So change the method to return a `BigInteger`. If you could have such large numbers as `int` instead then why would `BigInteger` exist in the first place?

Comment: If you're not familiar with HackerRank/LeetCode, you're supposed to keep the method signature. All you have to do is write the algorithm.

Comment: Bear in mind the submission evaluator is strictly looking at the lines written to the output file.  You can implement the `Solution` and `Result` class however you wish using any of the imports provided - which includes `java.math.*`.  The Java template is misguided since it specifies the method return as `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot, [the maximum value for int](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/apcsareview/VariableBasics/minAndMax.html#:%7E:text=The%20int%20type%20in%20Java,number%20from%20%2D2147483648%20to%202147483647.) is `2,147,483,647` (32 bits of value). If you need big numbers you must use the appropriate variable type.

If for some reason you want to avoid `BigInteger` at all and your are not going to do any arithmetic operation later, you can always return a `String`

---

About [the hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fibonacci-modified/problem), just modify the result variable type to `BigInteger`. Actually, they seem to be aware of the 32/64 bits issue... they are using a `String` value to prevent it.
[image]

There's no reason to keep the whole code-template structure. They just care about input/output. You are allowed to modify EVERYTHING but those two things.

This is their **input**:
[image]

This is their **output** (here you can see their output is expected to be a `String`):
[image]